# Will the CPU usage of a Fullnode increase?

Tags: iri-node, cpu

Will the CPU usage of a Fullnode increase?

I run a Fullnode (2 Core, 2.1 GHz, 6GB RAM), since 3 months.
First the CPU usage was low but since then it increase a lot.

In the meantime, the CPU is almost fully utilized by many txs.

Comment: I noted exactly the same. Since the last month the fullnode runs with CPU at 100% without any PoW occuring.

Answer (score 1):

this is interesting, many node operators complain that the load after synchronization is very low